# PDO connection select last id from table

Tags: pdo

I am trying to get the last id from my selected table. I know `lastinsertid();` sould work but it keeps returning a `0`. What am i doing wrong here?

```
   public function getlastadded()
{
    $Sql = 'SELECT * FROM agendaevent';
    $Stm = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($Sql);
    $Stm->execute();

    return $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->lastInsertId('id');
}
```

ps i am working in symfony if that makes a difference.

Comment: lastinsertid() works after insert, not select. Why do you want it?

Comment: i am adding a event but the events are linked 2 ways so i have to add the id to the event. tough i didnt know that it only works after inserts.@YourCommonSense

Comment: No, he means *you* are calling `lastInsertId()` after a select, not the INSERT. IIRC lastInsertId() works only for the connection on which an element was last created

Comment: @Pekka웃 okay i am a beginner i didnt know. is there a other way to do this?

Comment: **USE lastinsertid() RIGHT AFTER INSERT**. any other method will link anything but the proper id.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i am using symfonys entitys to insert so i am not writing the query. i am using the standart: `$agenda = new Agendaevent();
                                        $agenda->setName('blabla');`

Comment: So you should use Doctrine to get the actual id as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, friend:

```
 "SELECT * FROM agendaevent ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: Thats what i needed. Thanks!

Comment: I am no PHP expert, but i would like to know more about it, if you can sustain your comment.

Comment: @Laurence don't reward bad answers

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i dont know whats wrong with the answer. I am a beginner my self i am still studying. Its doing what i asked for i would like to know whats wrong with it.

Comment: I also don't know, Laurence. If someone can make a constructive comment, please do.

Comment: @Laurence this query will basically give you a random id, that could be unrelated to the entity you are working with. To get the actual id you should get it from the entity itself

Comment: @YourCommonSense the way they do it in the duplicate question u mean?

Comment: @Laurence exactly

Comment: @YourCommonSense i will look into it like i said i dont know much yet i am working in symfony for like 3 months now. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Guys, i had no intention to make this a bad answer. As i said, i'm no PHP expert, so i was trying to solve using just a SQL statement. Laurence, hope they can help you better.

Comment: @HenriqueGiuliani dont worry your help is much appreciated. I sould have tagged this with doctrine instead i think i see now.